# Java Connect 4 MinMax Algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, minmax, negamax

EDIT: I don't know why somebody links me a TicTacToe as duplicate for my question, there isn't even a MinMax-Algorithm in it.

Currently i'm working on a Connect4 game against the computer which should use the MinMax-Algorithm.
Before that, we wrote a TicTacToe which also uses the MinMax, but i'm not sure how to change my old algorithm to match the Connect4-Game :/.
In TicTacToe i evaluated each possible move with the win-conditions i wrote, it worked fine, but now it won't work with my new conditions.
My makeAMove etc. works fine!

These are my old conditions and the MinMax for TicTacToe:

//Player 1 wins

```
static boolean has1Won(int[][] array) {
gameBoard = array;
//Diagonal
if ((gameBoard[0][0] == gameBoard[1][1] && gameBoard[0][0] == gameBoard[2][2] && gameBoard[0][0] == 1)
|| (gameBoard[0][2] == gameBoard[1][1] && gameBoard[0][2] == gameBoard[2][0] && gameBoard[0][2] == 1)) {

    return true;
}
//Spalten/Zeilen
for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
if (((gameBoard[i][0] == gameBoard[i][1] && gameBoard[i][0] == gameBoard[i][2] && gameBoard[i][0] == 1) 
|| (gameBoard[0][i] == gameBoard[1][i] && gameBoard[0][i] == gameBoard[2][i] && gameBoard[0][i] == 1))) {
        return true;
    }
}
return false;
```

}

// Player 2 wins

```
static boolean has2Won(int[][] array) {
gameBoard = array;
    //Diagonal
    if ((gameBoard[0][0] == gameBoard[1][1] && gameBoard[0][0] == gameBoard[2][2] && gameBoard[0][0] == 2)
    || (gameBoard[0][2] == gameBoard[1][1] && gameBoard[0][2] == gameBoard[2][0] && gameBoard[0][2] == 2)) {

        return true;
    }
    //Spalten/Zeilen
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
        if (((gameBoard[i][0] == gameBoard[i][1] && gameBoard[i][0] == gameBoard[i][2] && gameBoard[i][0] == 2) 
        || (gameBoard[0][i] == gameBoard[1][i] && gameBoard[0][i] == gameBoard[2][i] && gameBoard[0][i] == 2))) {

        return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
```

}

As I said, i used these conditions for my MinMax like this:

```
public static int minimax(int depth, int turn) {

    if (Board.has1Won(Board.gameBoard)){
        return +1; // Der Computer gewinnt
    }
    if (Board.has2Won(Board.gameBoard)){
        return -1; // Der Spieler gewinnt
    }

    List<GameMove> gameMovesAvailable = GameMove.getAvailableGameMoves();
    if (gameMovesAvailable.isEmpty()){
        return 0; // Das Spiel endet unentschieden
    }
```

...

I'm not sure how i can get this to work with my new conditions:

I think i have to write an evaluating function which checks this for example (this is my wincondition for Rows):

```
boolean getWinnerInRow (Playboard brd){

    int count = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++){
            if (brd.gameBoard[i][j] != 0 && brd.gameBoard[i][j] ==   brd.gameBoard[i][j+1]){
                count++;
        } else {
                count = 1;
        }
        if (count >= 4){
          return true;
      }
    }
  }
    return false;
```

I know it's a lot of text, but maybe somebody can give me some useful tips :)

Thanks!

Max

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tic Tac Toe java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10961749/tic-tac-toe-java)

Comment: Please try to solve the problem yourself and ask a more specific question. Write some code, test it, and if it does not do what you expect it to do, come back with the specific error or wrong behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that your test to find the winner is correct. Try this (you'll need to change it a little bit, but at least I'm sure that it's correct):

```
public static boolean testWinner(int[][] game, int lastColumn, Integ e) {

    int lastRow = 0; 
    while (lastRow < 6 && game[lastRow][lastColumn] == 0) {
        lastRow++; 
    }
    lastRow = lastRow; 

    int i = 0; 
    int j = 0; 
    int currentPlayer = game[lastRow][lastColumn]; 
    e.setI(currentPlayer);
    int sequence = 0; 

    i = lastRow; 
    boolean b = i < 3
            && game[i][lastColumn] == currentPlayer 
            && game[i+1][lastColumn] == currentPlayer
            && game[i+2][lastColumn] == currentPlayer
            && game[i+3][lastColumn] == currentPlayer; 
    if(b) {
        return true; 
    }

    sequence = 0; 
    j = lastColumn; 
    do {
        j--;
    } while(0 < j && game[lastRow][j] == currentPlayer); 
    if(j < 0 || game[lastRow][j] != currentPlayer) {
        j++; 
    }
    while(j <= 6 && game[lastRow][j] == currentPlayer) {
        j++; 
        sequence++; 
    }
    if (sequence >= 4) {
        return true; 
    }


    sequence = 0; 
    i = lastRow; 
    j = lastColumn; 
    do {
        i--; 
        j--; 
    } while(0 < i && 0 < j && game[i][j] == currentPlayer); 
    if(i < 0 || j < 0 || game[i][j] != currentPlayer) {
        i++; 
        j++; 
    }
    while(i <= 5 && j <= 6 && game[i][j] == currentPlayer) {
        i++; 
        j++; 
        sequence++; 
    }
    if (sequence >= 4) {
        return true; 
    }


    sequence = 0; 
    i = lastRow; 
    j = lastColumn; 
    do {
        i++; 
        j--; 
    } while(i < 5 && 0 < j && game[i][j] == currentPlayer); 
    if (5 < i || j < 0 || game[i][j] != currentPlayer) {
        i--; 
        j++; 
    }
    while(0 <= i && j <= 6 && game[i][j] == currentPlayer) {
        i--; 
        j++; 
        sequence++; 
    }
    if (sequence >= 4) {
        return true; 
    }

    return false; 
}
```

Integ is just a class with an integer. I've created it because the wrapper is not really an object (can't pass by reference).

```
private static class Integ {

    private int i; 

    public Integ() {
        this.i = 0; 
    }

    public void increment() {
        this.i = this.i + 1; 
    }

    public int getI() {
        return this.i;
    }

    public void setI(int i) {
        this.i = i;
    }

}
```