# Algorithm to find winner of tic tac toe

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

What is the best optimal way to find out the winner in 3x3 Tic tac toe game where board is represented by a matrix ? Suggestions please

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tic Tac Toe java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10961749/tic-tac-toe-java)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming you are using a double dimension array of `Booleans`. Since a Boolean can have three values (null, true and false). Since only 2 players can play at any given time, then you only need three values. undefined, player 1 and player 2.

Here is a method that will work with any `Boolean` array as long as the size is more than `1`. It will return `true` if the `true` won, `false` if the `false` won and `null` if there isn't a winner yet.

```
public static Boolean getWinner(Boolean[][] grid) {
    if (grid == null)
        return null;
    int size = grid.length;
    if (size == 0)
        return null;
    if (size == 1 && (grid[0][0] != null)) {
        return grid[0][0];
    }
    boolean flag = true;
    // checks horizontal
    for (int index = 0; index <= size - 1; index++) {
        flag = true;
        for (int i = 1; i <= size - 1; i++) {
            if (grid[index][i] != grid[index][i - 1]) {
                flag = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (flag)
            return grid[index][0];
    }
    // checks vertical
    for (int index = 0; index <= size - 1; index++) {
        flag = true;
        for (int i = 1; i <= size - 1; i++) {
            if (grid[i][index] != grid[i - 1][index]) {
                flag = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (flag)
            return grid[0][index];
    }
    // checks diagonal
    flag = true;
    for (int index = 1; index <= size - 1; index++) {
        if (grid[index][index] != grid[index - 1][index - 1]) {
            flag = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (flag)
        return grid[0][0];
    flag = true;
    for (int index = 1; index <= size - 1; index++) {
        if (grid[size - index - 1][index] != grid[size - index][index - 1]) {
            flag = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (flag)
        return grid[size - 1][0];
    return null;
}
```

Sidenote: 
If you are using an `Enum` instead of a `Boolean` then you only need to change the two `Booleans` on the first line and all the `==` with `equals`

Comment: Thanks I successfully implemented it !!

Answer (score 3):

These functions should do it. I had used a character array when I made my tic-tac-toe.

```
int  rowcheck(char ch[3][3])
{
    int i;
    char ans;
    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        if(ch[i][0]==ch[i][1] && ch[i][1]==ch[i][2])
        {
            ans=ch[i][0];
            break;
        }
    }
    if(ans=='O')
    return 1;
    else if(ans=='X')
    return 2;
    else
    return 0;
}
int  colcheck(char ch[3][3])
{
    int i;
    char ans;
    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        if(ch[0][i]==ch[1][i] && ch[1][i]==ch[2][i])
        {
            ans=ch[0][i];
            break;
        }
    }
    if(ans=='O')
    return 1;
    else if(ans=='X')
    return 2;
    else
    return 0;
}
int  diagcheck(char ch[3][3])
{
    char ans;
    if(ch[0][0]==ch[1][1] && ch[1][1]==ch[2][2])
    ans=ch[0][0];
    if(ch[0][2]==ch[1][1] && ch[1][1]==ch[2][0])
    ans=ch[0][2];
    if(ans=='O')
    return 1;
    else if(ans=='X')
    return 2;
    else
    return 0;
}
```

Player 1 wins if 1 is returned else Player 2 wins.
Check out this link for more info:

https://keepkoding.wordpress.com/2015/12/12/everybody-knows-tic-tac-toe/

Mind you, this link is in C++ but the logic is simple to understand.

Comment: yes I understood the logic thanks !!!

Comment: But is there any better way like with less time complexity ?

Comment: If you need to check equality, I see no better way than this. Also, considering you are playing Tic Tac Toe, I see no reason to reduce time complexity. But if you must, the easiest way would be not to do such checks till at least 6 moves have been done. Considering only 9 moves can be done, this reduces more than 2/3rd of the time. If you liked my answer, please upvote it.

Comment: @AkshayBhat Umm maybe you should check my answer, for a more efficient algorithms that can give you the winner for an array of any given size.

Comment: @nickzoum Yeah, a bit of generalization is great. This was one of my first games that I just pasted the code of and at that point in time, I was just getting started with programming. It was in the later games that I started generalizations and proper comments. Thanks for the tip and feel free to check out my blog for other games like Snake or a Sudoku Solver.

Comment: Thank you guys !! It worked I had used enums and successfully modified it thanks for your valuable suggestions